# return value of multidimensional object for specific item

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the value of the item that was matched. I specifically want to know what is the Role- id of the matched item. I tried filtering to it but I only get a "true". I know that the value needs to be returned. It always matches correctly if exists, just need it to return the value of the Role ID.

```js
    const data = {
      PagingInfo: {
        "Bookmark": "6796",
        "HasMoreItems": true
      },
      "Items": [{
          OrgUnit: {
            Id: 2234
          },
          Role: {
            id: 100,
            "Name": "test A"
          }

        },
        {
          OrgUnit: {
            Id: 2244
          },
          Role: {
            id: 103,
            "Name: test b"
          }
        },
        {
          OrgUnit: {
            Id: 2245
          }
          Role: {
            id: 99,
            "Name: test C"
          }
        },
        {
          OrgUnit: {
            Id: 222
          }
          Role: {
            id: 98,
            "Name": "test E"
          }
        },
      ]
    };

    let array = data.Items;

    let match = '222';

    if (array.some(array => array.OrgUnit.Id === parseInt(match))) {
      console.log("Match found for " + match);
     return{
array.some(array => array.Role.Id
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Match not found for " + match);
    }

    match = '223';

    if (array.some(array => array.OrgUnit.Id === parseInt(match))) {
      console.log("Match found for " + match);
    } else {
      console.log("Match not found for " + match);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `I am trying to return the value of the item that was matched` do you mean if 2 ids are the same? i do not know the logic of your "match".. can you walk me through it?

Comment: `data.Items.find(item => item.OrgUnit.Id === 222).Role.id`

Comment: `"Name: test b"` is not a valid object property. There are several other syntax errors in your data

Comment: @Phil nice! Didn't know about `find`. I think you should write your solution as an answer

Comment: @mathiasfk I feel like there's a duplicate post that would have the same answer. Just trying to find it

Comment: @Phil please I went with your answer it works! if you want to "answer" it-please do and I will select

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using `array.some`, which will return true as soon as any value meeting the given condition is found.
What you really need to be using here is `array.find`, which will return the first matching value.

So in the case of looking for an OrgUnit with Id of 222, the matching item would be found with:

```
data.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === 222)
```

This would return

```
{
    OrgUnit: {
        Id: 222
    },
    Role: {
        id: 98,
        "Name": "test E"
    }
},
```

You can then do some test that a matching item has been found before returning the Role id.

Comment: What's the interrogation for?

Comment: The question mark in `item.OrgUnit?.Id` is an optional chaining operator. It means that if for some reason one of the items did not have an OrgUnit in the data, it would skip over it rather than throwing an error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @peteredhead I tried the data.find, but I get that it is not a function???

Comment: @Vzupo It would be worth checking in your case that data is an array and not something else like an object.

Comment: @Vzupo probably `data.Items.find`